# Mismatched input with binary operator parsing

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse an existing language in ANTLR that's currently being parsed using the Ruby library Parslet.

Here is a stripped down version of my grammar:

```
grammar FilterMin;

filter : condition_set;
condition_set: condition_set_type (property_condition)?;
condition_set_type: '=' | '^=';
property_condition: property_lhs CONDITION_SEPARATOR property_rhs;
property_lhs: QUOTED_STRING;
property_rhs: entity_rhs | contains_rhs;
contains_rhs: CONTAINS_OP '(' contains_value ')';
contains_value: QUOTED_STRING;
entity_rhs: NOT_OP? MATCH_OP? QUOTED_STRING;

// operators

MATCH_OP: '~';
NOT_OP: '^';
CONTAINS_OP: 'contains';
QUOTED_STRING: QUOTE STRING QUOTE;
STRING: (~['\\])*;
QUOTE: '\'';
CONDITION_SEPARATOR: ':';
```

This parses fails to parse both `='foo':'bar'` and `='foo':contains('bar')` with the same either: `mismatched input ':' expecting ':'` or `mismatched input ':contains(' expecting ':'`.

Why aren't these inputs parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `STRING` rule matches everything that isn't a backslash or a single quote. So it overlaps with all of your other lexical rules except `QUOTED_STRING`. Since the lexer will always pick the rule that produces the longest match and that's almost always `STRING`, your lexer will produce a bunch of `STRING` tokens and never any `CONDITION_SEPERATOR` tokens.

Since you never use `STRING` in your parser rules, it doesn't need to be an actual type of token. In fact, you never want `STRING` tokens to be generated, you only ever want it to be matched as part of a `QUOTED_STRING` token. Therefore it should be a `fragment`.

Comment: And STRING can match an empty string, which is not good either. It's too easy to forget that fact and assume something is consumed, later when such a rule is used somewhere. Better mark a rule optional in the caller.